# Exception Handler wont get triggered

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

in `startup.cs` I have added

```
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/error");
```

and in `/Home/error` action I have (Controller is `Home` and Action is `error`)

```
[Route("/error")]
    public IActionResult error()
    {
        TempData["ErrorCode"] = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
        return View();
    }
```

but it wasnt triggered for 404 status code when I tried.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A 404 isn't an exception.

Comment: how can i catch that then? what type of exceptions go through this? im trying `int.parse("s")` just to get it to throw an exception but that doesnt work either VS instead takes over and shows me that it cant convert "s" to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy's comment 404 not an exception so to get exception codes add middleware UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute it'll catch page status like 404,500 and so on so your startup.cs like

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Index/{0}");
```

Note: I assume that error is a separate controller, you can use same concept to make it an action method inside Home controller

Error controller as below

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
        [Route("/Error/Index/{code:int}")]
        public IActionResult Index(int code)
        {
            //code will be 404,500 or whatever
            //write your code here to handle this code for example
            //I return view with error view model
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { Code = (ErrorCodes)code });
        }
}
```

now if you redirect to not existing page you will get code = 404